# Roles not working in ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication

I have a web-site which uses forms auth and ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider. I have an Action in controller like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "jira-developers")]
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult MonitorForm()
        {
            var list = Dal.GetActualData();
            return View(list);
        }
```

I'm totally sure that my user is in group with Name="jira-developers", but auth fails. If i remove Roles parameter, the auth will work fine.

What am i doing wrong? I'll be gratefull for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As nobody gave me an answer i'll answer this question myself. ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider can only handle auth and to enable roles management i had to specify rolesManager. I implemented my own RoleProvider (because i need some specific functionality) and now my Web.Config looks like this:

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name=".ADAuthCookie" loginUrl="~/Account/Login" timeout="45" slidingExpiration="false" protection="All" />
</authentication>
<membership defaultProvider="ADMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="ADMembershipProvider"
         type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider"
         connectionStringName="ADConnectionString"
         attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" />
  </providers>
</membership>
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="AdRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="AdRoleProvider" type="InternalAutomation.Providers.AdRoleProvider"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
```

Comment: can you please list the the custome role provider here also

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the role defined in your Roles table? (Depending on the version you're using the table could be named slightly different than my screen shot below)

[image: Roles in Database Table]

You should have an entry with a 'RoleName' of "jira-developers".
The user hitting the action should also have an entry in the '...UsersInRoles' table.

Comment: What table do you mean? I want to use Active directory Users and Groups as Roles